# Symfony - finding associated items, based on foreign key

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm having a little bit of a struggle, trying to come up with a solution for the following:

I have a bunch of items, that are just content items, i.e. title etc
I then can associate a tag to such items, in a many-to-many relationship

What I'm looking to do, is find all associated items, based on their tags.

Example:
     Item
     id
     1
     2
     3
     4

```
ItemTag
id | item_id | tag_id
1  |    1    |    1
2  |    1    |    2
3  |    2    |    2
4  |    4    |    3
5  |    4    |    4

Tag
id | tag
1  | Test_1
2  | Test_2
3  | Test_3
```

Now, what I'm looking to do is, let's say i was on item 1, i need to find all associated items based on the item_tag

I am using Propel, so I'm looking for a criteria query...

Is this a good way of doing things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this method (not tested) on Item should work:

```
public function getItemsWithSameTags()
{
    $tags = $this->getTags();

    $tagIDs = array();
    foreach ($tags as $tag)
    {
        $tagIDs[] = $tag->getId();
    }

    return ItemQuery::create()
        ->useItemTagQuery()
            ->where('ItemTag.TagId IN ?', $tagIDs)
        ->endUse()
        ->find();
}
```